# Azure devops SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task is not able to drop the database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to use `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment` to drop the database. But not sure why I am getting a syntax error in the output, Here is my code.

I am using windows-latest as an agent.

```
    - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'connect-using-spn-demo-dev'
        AuthenticationType: 'server'
        ServerName: 'abc-sql-server.database.windows.net'
        DatabaseName: 'master'
        SqlUsername: 'saadminuser'
        SqlPassword: 'abcd@1234'
        deployType: 'InlineSqlTask'
        sqlInline: drop database demo-dev-restore
        IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
      displayName: Dropping database
```

But not sure why I am getting the below-mentioned error.

> ##[error]Incorrect syntax near '-'. 
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure , Line 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-

Comment: The problem is with `drop database demo-dev-restore`. You can't subtract `dev` from `demo`, nor `restore` from `dev`, which is what SQL interprets that as. Have you tried quoting the database name yet? e.g.: `drop database [demo-dev-restore]`

Comment: 100% correct answer. It Worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax error replace "drop database demo-dev-restore" with drop database [demo-dev-restore] and it worked